# Raspberry pi 4 controle GPIO with java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I want to controle a 16*2 lcd display on my raspberry pi4 with java. The problem is that Pi4J - the solution to modify the gpios with java is not updated to pi4. Is there another solution? This error occures when I start the programm:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/desktop/gpio $ sudo ./start.sh
```

<--Pi4J--> GPIO Control Example ... started. Maista
Unable to determine hardware version. I see: Hardware   : BCM2711
,

- expecting BCM2708 or BCM2709.
  If this is a genuine Raspberry Pi then please report this
  to projects@drogon.net. If this is not a Raspberry Pi then you
  are on your own as wiringPi is designed to support the
  Raspberry Pi ONLY.

Comment: Did you contact projects@drogon.net?   Or look at the pi4j web site?  Seems like the authors would be best equipped to talk about their code.

Comment: If you don't find what you need, you should look at raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user13784117, the WiringPi dev has thrown the towel. Contacting him will likely not achieve anything.

Comment: The promise of open source is that if the author won't fix it, you can do it yourself  :-)

Comment: For most of the LCDs (often hd44780) there is a driver in the kernel. Use it and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 5):

Pi4J uses WiringPi to control the GPIOs. So please update it to version 2.52 as this one supports the Raspberry Pi 4, see http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/

```
$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.50
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb
$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.52
```

You can find a full java+pi4j+lcd example on my blog on https://webtechie.be/post/2020-01-26-openweathermap-forecast-on-lcd-with-raspberry-pi-java-and-pi4j/

Comment: Nice! Can you accept my answer as the solution John ?

Comment: are you using Raspberry Pi 4 with Pi4j v.1.2 for the weather forecast app?

Comment: For my book I used a Pi 3 for the hardware experiments, but with Pi4J indeed as you can see on https://github.com/FDelporte/JavaOnRaspberryPi/blob/master/Chapter_09_Pi4J/java-pi4j-lcddisplay/src/main/java/be/webtechie/pi4jgpio/App.java#L34 and https://github.com/FDelporte/JavaOnRaspberryPi/blob/master/Chapter_09_Pi4J/java-pi4j-lcddisplay/src/main/java/be/webtechie/pi4jgpio/lcd/LcdOutput.java#L104. I didn't try this specific example on a Pi 4 yet, but other ones worked without any issue after upgrading WiringPi to version 2.52.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason it was not working for me, is that `sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb` installs gpio in `/usr/bin/gpio` but there was another gpio file in `/usr/local/bin/gpio` which was taking precedence. You can find if this is the case for you by running `which gpio`.

I renamed the old file from `gpio` to `gpio.old` (I did not want to delete it, just in case) and executed `sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb` again. Now when I run `which gpio` I find the correct executable.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](https://calpilot.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/raspberry-pi-and-pi4j-tutorial-1/) that can help you.
It seems easy to understand, you just need to change some xml files.

Comment: besides being a link-only answer this tutorial refers to an 2015-version of pi4j (version 0.0.5) - since 1.2 is out this answer is not really helpful