# Raspberry Pi4 with Pi4j Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, pi4j

I am trying to run a simple test on my Raspberry Pi4 using the pi4j java library v1.2. Somehow it's not doing anything. I also don't see any errors on console. It just finishes after 2 seconds.
I'm expecting the LED light to turn on and turn off after 2 seconds.

I also updated my gpio binary to v2.52 as per this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63433316/607637 but it's still the same. Also, the command `gpio write 19 1` is not doing anything.

**GPIO**

```
pi@gtpi:~ $ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.52
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Pi 4B, Revision: 02, Memory: 4096MB, Maker: Sony 
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
pi@gtpi:~ $ gpio write 19 1  ///---> this also doesn't do anything
```

**Java App: uses  `com.pi4j:pi4j-core:1.2`**

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.*;
public class Pi4 {
  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    GpioPinDigitalOutput op = GpioFactory.getInstance().provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_19);

    op.high();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    op.low();
 }
}
```

However, a python script that I wrote to do the same is working:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

red = LED(19)
red.on()
sleep(2)
red.off()
```

Question: what else do I need to do to make the Java app working(turning on the LED)? Is it not compatible with Pi4 at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears its answered here:

- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113511
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111679

It looks Pi4j is using a different pin numbering scheme.  "Under the hood", WiringPi is used to control the GPIOs.

So, I needed to tell it to use Broadcom pin numbering scheme using:

`GpioFactory.setDefaultProvider(new RaspiGpioProvider(RaspiPinNumberingScheme.BROADCOM_PIN_NUMBERING));`

Now its working:

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.*;
public class Pi4 {
  public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    GpioFactory.setDefaultProvider(new RaspiGpioProvider(RaspiPinNumberingScheme.BROADCOM_PIN_NUMBERING));

    GpioPinDigitalOutput op = GpioFactory.getInstance().provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_19);

    op.high();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    op.low();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Pi4J uses the WiringPi numbering scheme by default.
This is a nice overview where you have physical pin numbers (1-40), BMC and WiringPi (WPI) next to each other.

This is further described in my book "[Getting Started with Java on the Raspberry Pi](https://webtechie.be/books/)". Yes, I know, this is shameless self-promotion ;-)

[image]